# HTML5 audio clicking the progress bar to move to a different time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                var counter = 0;
                var numOfTracks = $(".audio-player").length;
                $("#play-bt").click(function(){
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].play();
                    $("#message").text("Music started");
                })

                $("#pause-bt").click(function(){
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].pause();
                    $("#message").text("Music paused");
                })

                $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].pause();
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].currentTime = 0;
                    $("#message").text("Music Stopped");
                })

                $("#next-bt").click(function(){
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].pause();
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].currentTime = 0;
                    counter++;


                    if(counter > numOfTracks - 1){
                        counter = 0 ;
                    }

                    $(".audio-player")[counter].play();
                    $("#message").text("Next Track started");
                })

                $("#prev-bt").click(function(){
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].pause();
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].currentTime = 0;
                    counter--;
                    $(".audio-player")[counter].play();
                    $("#message").text("Previous Track");
                })

                $(".audio-player").bind('timeupdate', function(){

                    //Gets the whole duration of the track.
                    //No idea kung saan ko ilalagay sa UI**IMPLEMENT LATER**
                    var track_length = $(".audio-player")[counter].duration;
                    var secs = $(".audio-player")[counter].currentTime;
                    var progress = (secs/track_length) * 100;

                    $('#progressbar').css({'width' : progress * 2});

                    //Will Use these later on production
                    //NOTE DO NOT DELETE
                    //Track Minutes
                    var tcMins = parseInt(secs/60);
                    //Track Seconds
                    var tcSecs = parseInt(secs - (tcMins * 60));

                    if (tcSecs < 10) { tcSecs = '0' + tcSecs; }

                    // Display the time. REMEMBER
                    $('#timecode').html(tcMins + ':' + tcSecs);
                })
            })
        </script>
            <style>

        /*Seperate this some time in the development*/

        #playerContainer{ 
            background-color: #A8A8A8  ; 
            width: 260px; 
            height: 55px;
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
        }
        /* Player Controls */

        /*list items of controls */

        #playerControls li { 
            display: block; 
            width: 32px; 
            height: 32px; 
            padding: 0px;
            float: left; 
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #playerControls { list-style: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;}

        /*Images for each li items items */
        #play-bt { background: url('icons/glyphicons_173_play.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat }
        #pause-bt {background: url('icons/glyphicons_174_pause.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
        #next-bt { background: url('icons/glyphicons_176_forward.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat}
        #prev-bt {background: url('icons/glyphicons_172_rewind.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;}

        /*Progress Stuff*/


        /*Remember to manipulate its width via javascript later*/
        #progressContainer 
        { 
            background-color:#e0e0e0;
            height: 14px; 
            width: 256px; 
            float: left;
            margin-left: 0px;
        }

        #progressbar {background-color: #1384bb; height:14px; width:0%; }

            </style>
    </head>
<body>
            <audio class ="audio-player"  name= "audio-player" src="04-zedd-stars_come_out_(terravita_remix).ogg" >
                <p>Sorry your file doesn't support html5</p>
            </audio>
            <!--Second Track For Testing Purposes-->
            <audio  class ="audio-player" name= "audio-player" src="01-hard_rock_sofa-quasar.mp3" ></audio>

            <div id="message"></div>
                <div id = "playerContainer">

                    <ul id =  "playerControls" >
                        <li id = "prev-bt"></li>
                        <li id= "play-bt"></li>
                        <li id= "pause-bt"></li> 
                        <li id = "next-bt"></li>
                        <li id= "stop-bt" ></li>
                        <li><span id ="timecode"></span></li>

                    </ul>
                        <div id="progressContainer"><!-- Progess bars container //-->
                            <div id="progressbar"></div>
                        </div>
                </div>

            </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

How can I click a certain part of my progress bar so that I can move it to a different time in the track? I have no idea on how I am going to do that. any ideas ?

Comment: I did it with a range slider, you don't have to. Because I didn't want to spend years working on this for you, it's only supported in Chrome. [You can see the working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RuJ94/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given some html that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <video class="video">
        <source></source>
    </video>
    <progress min="0" max="100" value="0"></progress>
    <div class="controls"></div>
</div>
```

In order to seek to a specific time in the video as a result of a click event the js would look like this:

```
var player = document.querySelector("video");
var progressBar = document.querySelector("progress");
progressBar.addEventListener("click", seek);

function seek(e) {
    var percent = e.offsetX / this.offsetWidth;
    player.currentTime = percent * player.duration;
    progressBar.value = percent / 100;
}
```

However, this doesn't address how to seek on a click/drag (like most video players do). include script

Comment: just stating the obvious here.

it should `progressBar.value = percent * 100;`, since percent will come out to be fraction.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question today because I am creating a custom HTML5 video player and had the same question. Just in regards to video instead of audio. The process should work the same though.

I found this article and was able to incorporate the progress bar part of it into my player. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Instead of using a `progressbar` element, like I was doing, or a `div` element, like you're doing, the trick here is to use a canvas element instead.

```
<canvas id='progress-bar' width="200" height="20" style="border:1px solid green;">canvas not supported</canvas>
```

Then in your JavaScript, create a handle to reference it by

```
var mediaPlayer;
var progressBar;
var canvas;
```

When the document loads, initialize everything including the progress bar items

```
mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
canvas = document.getElementById('progress-bar');

canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('progress-bar');

    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    } //get the latest windows event if it isn't set
    try {
        //calculate the current time based on position of mouse cursor in canvas box
        mediaPlayer.currentTime = mediaPlayer.duration * (e.offsetX / canvas.clientWidth);
    }
    catch (err) {
    // Fail silently but show in F12 developer tools console
        if (window.console && console.error("Error:" + err));
    }
}, true);

mediaPlayer.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateProgressBar, false);
```

Then create a function outside of your initialization function for the `timeupdate` listener to call and automatically update the progress bar for you

```
function updateProgressBar() {        
    mediaPlayer = document.getElementById('media-video');
    //get current time in seconds
    var elapsedTime = Math.round(mediaPlayer.currentTime);
    //update the progress bar
    if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        //clear canvas before painting
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
        var fWidth = (elapsedTime / mediaPlayer.duration) * (canvas.clientWidth);
        if (fWidth > 0) {
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, fWidth, canvas.clientHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't completely cleaned it up yet. Hence the redundant handles to the same id. But I'm sure you get the picture.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks for posting, but just a quick note - in your `updateProgressBar()` function, the first line of code is re-executing the `getElementById()` selector to update mediaPlayer, but the mediaPlayer will not have changed from when you selected it onload. So you can completely remove this line.

Comment: Additionally, your defined `progressBar` and `canvas` variables are redundant. You can remove the `progressBar` variable as it is not used.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can save someone some time.  If you're trying to set this up in an Angular app, you'll notice `this` is your controller context.  So you'll need to use `e.srcElement.clientWidth` for this to work.

```
vm.setPosition = function(e){

  var percent = ((e.offsetX / e.srcElement.clientWidth));

  vm.songObject.setProgress(percent);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

I wrote about that in [Working with HTML5 multimedia components – Part 3: Custom controls](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html), scroll down to "Adding a progress bar".

Comment: doesn't answer question. user is looking to update song position based on click on custom progress bar

Comment: This completely does not answer the question. This appears to be nothing more than an advertisement for your article. Even the section you refer to in your article has absolutely nothing to do with the question as posed.

Comment: Irelevant to the question

Comment: And yet it's the marked answer so the original poster clearly found it answered his/her question.