# How jump ahead in audio by the amount clicked on a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a progress bar where the user can click through the audio file. Currently, the function runs however the UI does not update, and I am not able to click through the audio.

**How can I update the UI and click through it?**

Source: https://www.adobe.com/devnet/archive/html5/articles/html5-multimedia-pt3.html

```js
function updateProgress() {
   var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
   var value = 0;
   if (audioElement.currentTime > 0) {
      value = Math.floor((100 / audioElement.duration) * audioElement.currentTime);
      console.log(audioElement.currentTime);
      progress.style.width = value + "%";
      console.log(value + "%");
   }
   // progress.style.width = value + "%";
   // console.log(value + "%");
}
```

```css
#progressBar {
   border:1px solid #aaa;
   color:#fff;
   width:250px;
   height:20px;
}
#progress {
   background-color:#ff0000; // red
   height:20px;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
      <div id="progressBar"><span id="progress"></span></div>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706177/html5-audio-clicking-the-progress-bar-to-move-to-a-different-time/32804559) related question may be helpful

Comment: @UrbanConor perfect, that did it! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 audio clicking the progress bar to move to a different time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706177/html5-audio-clicking-the-progress-bar-to-move-to-a-different-time)